# A database query error in Wikimedia 1.27.4

Tags: vulnerability

I have a website running Wikimedia 1.27.4 , When I insert (--) symbol in search box I get this error message

```
A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.
```

[image]

I got some question about this issue:
Can you explain to me this behavior ?
It's really vulunrabilitie in the software?

Is-it exploitable?

Comment: Can you try running SQLMap, and see what it says?

Comment: Yes I try it and nothing